# Is there a lightweight APT repository browser GUI?

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

I find Synaptic a rather convenient tool for browsing through the repositories looking what's in them but I prefer to use command line to install the actual packages (to let bash maintain history of what I have installed manually) and it annoys me that I can't use apt-get when Synaptic is running. I would also like to be able to use a nice GUI to browse remote repositories without attaching them. Does anybody happen to know a tool I might like?

Comment: `/var/log/apt/history.log` should show which apps where installed manually (including the command used). Synaptic can be run without root, meaning it can't apply changes, or lock the databases.

Comment: Synaptic download size is ~1.3mb. How much more lightweight can you get!

Comment: @PrahladYeri I don't mean download size, I mean the behaviour.

Comment: @muru "Synaptic can be run without root..."  - how? It asks for my password every time I launch it.

Comment: Run `synaptic` from the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synaptic asks for root because the Synaptic `.desktop` file launches `synaptic-pkexec`:

```
$ grep Exec /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop 
Exec=synaptic-pkexec
```

Running just `synaptic` will avoid the root requirement, preventing Synaptic from locking the databases, or making any changes.
You can create your own `.desktop` file which will invoke just `synaptic`, running it as a normal user:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/synaptic.desktop
sed -i 's/-pkexec//;/^Name/s/$/ (non root)/' ~/.local/share/applications/synaptic.desktop
```

I don't know of any browser for an unconnected repository.

Comment: Won't installing things through synaptic mark them as manually installed as well?

Comment: @Seth it should.